# Need solution with python program lagging

Tags: python, geometry, mouse, lag, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard, mouse
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

zone1 = [(332, 1), (1051, 721), (1770, 1)]
zone2 = [(1770, 1), (1051, 721), (1770, 1439)]
zone3 = [(1770, 1439), (1051, 721), (332, 1436)]
zone4 = [(332, 1436), (1051, 721), (332, 1)]

zone_key_mapping = {
    'zone1': ['ctrl', 'up'],
    'zone2': ['ctrl', 'right'],
    'zone3': ['ctrl', 'down'],
    'zone4': ['ctrl', 'left']
}
active = False
zone_keys_pressed = {zone: False for zone in zone_key_mapping}

def on_press(key):
    global active

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        exit()

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('g'):
        active = not active

        if not active:
            print("Deactivated")
            for zone in zone_key_mapping:
                zone_keys_pressed[zone] = False
        else:
            print("Activated")

def on_move(x, y):
    global active

    if not active:
        return

    current_position = Point(x, y)

    for zone in zone_key_mapping:
        if is_inside_zone(current_position, globals()[zone]) and not zone_keys_pressed[zone]:
            perform_action(zone)
            zone_keys_pressed[zone] = True
        elif not is_inside_zone(current_position, globals()[zone]):
            zone_keys_pressed[zone] = False

def is_inside_zone(point, zone):
    polygon = Polygon(zone)
    return polygon.contains(point)

def perform_action(zone):
    keys = zone_key_mapping.get(zone, [])

    if keys:
        pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
        pyautogui.press(keys[1])
        pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener, mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move) as mouse_listener:
    listener.join()
    mouse_listener.join()
```

The certain buttons get pressed when mouse cursor goes from one triangular zones on the screen to another. The problem is that the moment cursor crosses the border of the zones it starts lagging for about a second. Can someone help me fix or somehow optimize that code

The code must run smoothly but it doesn't

Comment: Each "zone" is repeatedly cast to a `Polygon()` every time the mouse moves. Worse, you sometimes do that twice by calling `is_inside_zone()` twice.